# How to join 2 strings and make them array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do:

```
var lat = data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-19"];
var lng = data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-20"];
var comboCoords = lat+","+lng;
```

But `comboCoords` is a string while I need it as an array and push that

I tried:

```
coords.push([lat, lng]);
```

But since I need to split them because I do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
   var pin = coords[i][0].split(',');
   var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pin[0], pin[1]);
```

I get

> TypeError: coords[i][0].split is not a function

I tried

```
var comboCoords = JSON.parse(lat+","+lng);
coords.push(comboCoords);
```

But I get

> Unexpected token , in JSON at position 6

if I `console.log` `lat` and `lng` I get:

```
["39.213"]0: "39.213"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
(index):575 ["9.126"]
```

Comment: What are `lat` and `lng`?

Comment: @JackBashford just updated with lat and lng console log

Comment: This post seems to be lacking alot of details. I am guessing that there is a loop to collect a number of coords and put them in a new array of coords as arrays. Please clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish. Do not ask X when you want to know Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you want something like:

```
coords = [
  [
    39.213,
    9.126
  ],
  [
    39.225,
    9.135
  ]
];
```

Essentially a matrix, an Array of Arrays that contain 2 elements each.

I would suggest an Array of Objects:

```
coords = [
  {
    lat: 39.213,
    lng: 9.126
  },
  {
    lat: 39.225,
    lng: 9.135
  }
];
```

While you're iterating your `data`, you can populate this into the array.

```
var coords = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  coords.push({
    lat: data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-19"],
    lng: data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-20"]
  });
}
```

You will now have an array of `coords` that contains objects. You can access it like:

```js
var data = [{
  "usp-custom-90": {
    "usp-custom-19": 39.213,
    "usp-custom-20": 9.126
  }
}, {
  "usp-custom-90": {
    "usp-custom-19": 39.225,
    "usp-custom-20": 9.135
  }
}];
var coords = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  coords.push({
    lat: data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-19"],
    lng: data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-20"]
  });
}

console.log(coords[0].lat + "," + coords[0].lng);
console.log(coords[1]['lat'] + "," + coords[1]['lng']);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `lat` and `lng` are arrays. You can't `split` an array - spread into the pushed array:

```
coords.push([...lat, ...lng]);
```

Or just use index access:

```
coords.push([lat[0], lng[0]]);
```

Comment: thing is I believe the json is broken, if I do that I get  Array(2), "40.7197406, 8.563512299999957", "40.7272074, 8.575266499999998", Array(2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the [] in the push statement.

```
var arr = [];
var lat = data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-19"];
var lng = data[i]["usp-custom-90"]["usp-custom-20"];
var comboCoords = lat+","+lng;
arr.push(comboCoords);
```

Comment: they will be separated tho, there after I won't be able to use  `var pin = coords[i][0].split(',');`

Comment: Then just use `var comboCoords = lat+","+lng;` then push it to the array `arr.push(comboCoords);` You can verify the result using  `alert(JSON.stringify(arr));`

Comment: is it not what I did in the question?

Comment: For some reason you parsed your data. I have reproduced an working example: https://jsfiddle.net/vk8216da/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var string1="Content1";
    var string2="Content2";

    var array = string1+string2.split(" ");

   var output =""

   for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 output += array[i];
   }

     console.log(output);
```